# Ask whether the user is sure to leave the site (XHTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, confirm

When a user leaves one page of my website, there should be a warning message which gives the user the option to stay on the page:

"Are you sure that you want to close this page?"

It doesn't matter if the next page is an internal or external page.

I thought this could be done with the onUnload event handler, couldn't it?

```
<body onunload="confirmClose()">
```

The confirmClose() function must then show a message box with two buttons so that the user can choose between "Really leave" or "Stay".

```
function confirmClose() {
    return confirm('Really leave this page?')
}
```

But this function can't stop the unload, right?

Do you have a solution for my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a solution to your problem: don't ask the user to confirm leaving your site.  It's nothing but annoying.

Comment: There are legitimate uses for this, for example when there is user input that would be lost when leaving the page.

Comment: I must agree with both of you. It is really annoying but can be useful, though. I want to use it in an adequate case where it prevents the user from losing data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `onbeforeunload` event. Note that it can **only** return a text string to include in the dialog the browser will display when the event is called. You can't tweak the dialog beyond that, nor can you trigger your own `confirm` as you're trying to do.

I'd note that this is very, very annoying behaviour except in a few specific situations. Unless you're saving me from significant data loss with this, please don't do it.

Comment: Thank you very much! All answers were good and helpful - but I have to choose one as the best. ;) So I choose your one.

Answer (score 5):

You can only provide the text.  The browser handles the dialog box (security reasons).  Here is some code you can use:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    var msg = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';

    // For IE and Firefox
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = msg;
    }

    // For Safari / chrome
    return msg;
}
```

Try this out on different browsers, though.  You'll notice the message should be constructed differently depending on the different browsers' dialog wording.

Here is what I use:

```
if (IsChrome) {
    return 'You were in the middle of editing. You will lose your changes if you leave this page';
} else {
    return 'You were in the middle of editing. Press OK to leave this page (you will lose your changes).';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser takes care of displaying the confirm window.
You need to return the string with the message that you want to ask. Also, you may want to use `onbeforeunload` for cross browser compatibility.